# About regular task

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am using a cent OS server and a Mysql database.  And I have a task which will execute every day to generate some useful info from one big table to a small table.  Which technology be applicable to me.  My server running an apache server with php support. should I use php to reach this task? or there have other technology more applicable to my requirement?

Comment: is this task written in php? or shell?

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala  I familiar php than shell, so I prefer to write it in php.

Answer (score 1):

cron jobs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

If you are the admin of the server the easily you can use php, a simple shell script (actually sql script inside shell script). If you're not the admin then you've to focus on the conventional way unless